# Pubsub between two nodes in IPFS

Tags: node.js, publish-subscribe, ipfs, libp2p

I'm trying to send messages between two IPFS nodes.
The daemon that I'm running is based on go-ipfs, and is running with the flag:

```
ipfs daemon --enable-pubsub-experiment
```

I've coded two .js files, one is for the subscriber:

```
const IPFS = require('ipfs')
const topic = 'topic';
const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
const msg_buffer = Buffer.from('message');

const ipfs = new IPFS({
  repo: repo(),
  EXPERIMENTAL: {
    pubsub: true
  },
  config: {
    Addresses: {
      Swarm: [
        '/dns4/ws-star.discovery.libp2p.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p-websocket-star'
      ]
    }
  }
})

ipfs.once('ready', () => ipfs.id((err, info) => {
  if (err) { throw err }
  console.log('IPFS node ready with address ' + info.id)
  subscribeToTopic()
}))

function repo () {
  return 'ipfs-' + Math.random()
}

const receiveMsg = (msg) => {
  console.log(msg.data.toString())
}

const subscribeToTopic = () => {
  ipfs.pubsub.subscribe(topic, receiveMsg, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(`failed to subscribe to ${topic}`, err)
    }
    console.log(`subscribed to ${topic}`)
  })
}
```

And one is for the publisher:

```
const IPFS = require('ipfs');
const topic = 'topic';
const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
const msg_buffer = Buffer.from('message');

const ipfs = new IPFS({
  repo: repo(),
  EXPERIMENTAL: {
    pubsub: true
  },
  config: {
    Addresses: {
      Swarm: [
        '/dns4/ws-star.discovery.libp2p.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p-websocket-star'
      ]
    }
  }
})

ipfs.once('ready', () => ipfs.id((err, info) => {
  if (err) { throw err }
  console.log('IPFS node ready with address ' + info.id)
  publishToTopic()
}))

function repo () {
  return 'ipfs-' + Math.random()
}

const publishToTopic = () => {
  ipfs.pubsub.publish(topic, msg_buffer, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(`failed to publish to ${topic}`, err)
    }
    // msg was broadcasted
    console.log(`published to ${topic}`)
    console.log(msg_buffer.toString())
  })
}
```

I've runned the .js scripts with:

```
node file.js
```

But the subscriber didn't receive any message from the subscriber and I don't know why.

What is the correct way to connect two nodes in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "The daemon that I'm running is based on go-ipfs"? Are you run `const ipfs = new IPFS` you start a JS ipfs node... Also, are you trying to run this in the browser, or in nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but the npm package `ipfs` is an entire implementation of IPFS protocol and it creates a node when the constructor is called, that's why `ipfs daemon ...` is not necesary. If you need to use it as API with the ipfs daemon you can use the [ipfs-http-client](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-http-client) package.

You can use [ipfs-pubsub-room](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/ipfs-pubsub-room) and it has a working example based on this package [ipfs-pubsub-room-demo](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/ipfs-pubsub-room-demo).

I hope it helps, I'm still learning this tech too.

Comment: Hi nahuallt, I can't make work ipfsd-ctrl with ipfs-pubsub-room, it is a controller that spawns a daemon process and uses the http-client to handle this daemon, I get some errors related to libp2p when I try to use the client node API, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Currently (2019-09-17) most nodes in the ipfs network don't have pubsub enabled, so chances your pubsub messages will pass through are slim.
You can try to establish direct connection between your nodes, as explained here:[managing swarm connections in ipfs](https://medium.com/pinata/speeding-up-ipfs-pinning-through-swarm-connections-b509b1471986)

Essentially:

1. Run "ipfs id" on internet accessible node
2. Inspect output, get the address (it should look like this /ip4/207.210.95.74/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmesRgiWSBeMh4xbUEHUKTzAfNqihr3fFhmBk4NbLZxXDP
   )
3. On the other node establish direct connection:

   ipfs swarm connect /ip4/207.210.95.74/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmesRgiWSBeMh4xbUEHUKTzAfNqihr3fFhmBk4NbLZxXDP

Answer (score 0):

Please see the ipfs Github [example](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/tree/master/examples/browser-exchange-files), as it shows how to connect two js-ipfs browser nodes together via WebRTC.